# get Firefox to trust expired Charles CA Certificate

Tags: firefox, proxy, ssl, certificate

When I use the security certificate supplied by Charles Proxy in Firefox (35.0) to decrypt SSL traffic, it results in Firefox showing

> The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate has
>   expired. 
>   (Error code: sec_error_expired_issuer_certificate)

According to [this](https://muffinresearch.co.uk/proxying-connections-from-ffos/) article:

> the cause of the expired certificate is due to the way that Firefox
>   validates certs. The more recent versions of Firefox only allow certs
>   with start dates after the unix epoch (1st Jan 1970). As the Charles
>   CA cert has a start year of 1899 it's seen as expired.

Is there any way to get Firefox to accept certificates with start dates before the Unix epoch? Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got around the issue by creating my own CA by following this guide http://0x74696d.com/posts/CharlesSSL/

Then, I went to Firefox settings > Advanced > Certificates > View Certificates > Import and added my ca_cert.pem.

Comment: cheers man, works for me until Karl can update his Firefox cert. Here's my generated certs if anyone's lazy:
http://www.georgiecasey.com/charles_proxy_firefox_ssl_certs_fix/

I'm sure there's some huge security vulnerability in accepting random certs as authorities that someone smarter than me will warn people about, so everyone should really generate their own.

Answer (score -3):

Work around... in about:config find and change value of security.tls.version.min to 1 ... may require a restart of Firefox
https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/10/14/the-poodle-attack-and-the-end-of-ssl-3-0/

Comment: The question appears to not have anything to do with POODLE, and I fail to see how this does anything to help the OP's problem. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I would agree with you Michael.  I don't see the connection to POODLE.

Comment: besides which, my security.tls.version.min was already set to 1 and it didn't solve the issue